# Paypal REST API does not show up payment amount on Paypal Sandbox or live sites

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Rest api is working fine but its not showing amount in order summery 
"In Order summery amount is not showing but description is showing?"
   "I am using below code to pass amount and description"

```
require DIR . '/../bootstrap.php';
use PayPal\Api\Address;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\FundingInstrument;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;


$charge = trim($_POST['amount']);
$currency = trim($_POST['currency']);
$desc = trim($_POST['desc']);
$get_url=trim($_SESSION['get_url']);


$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPayment_method("paypal");

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency($currency);
$amount->setTotal($charge);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$transaction->setDescription($desc);





}

"In order summery its showing description but amount is not showing."
Please help me to sort out this problem"
Thank for you help.

Sunil
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create and add ItemList with at least one item to your transaction.
Here is an example:

```
$payer = new Payer();                          
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");            

$amount = new Amount();                        
$amount->setCurrency($paymentCurrency);        
$amount->setTotal($paymentAmount);             

$item = new Item();                            
$item->setQuantity(1);                         
$item->setName($paymentDescription);           
$item->setPrice($paymentAmount);               
$item->setCurrency($paymentCurrency);          

$itemList = new ItemList();                    
$itemList->setItems(array($item));             

$transaction = new Transaction();              
$transaction->setAmount($amount);              
$transaction->setItemList($itemList);          

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();            
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);       
$redirectUrls->setCancelUrl($cancelUrl);       

$payment = new Payment();                      

$payment->setIntent("sale");                   
$payment->setPayer($payer);                    
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);      
$payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,But still no fix,When i add these two item and itemlist in my page, its showing blank page.  $item = new Item();                            
$item->setQuantity(1);                         
$item->setName($paymentDescription);           
$item->setPrice($paymentAmount);               
$item->setCurrency($paymentCurrency);          

$itemList = new ItemList();                    
$itemList->setItems(array($item));